# How to find the block, when contract was deployed

Tags: contract-deployment, events

I have contract address, and I want to find the block number, when it was deployed, to use it for loading events for this contract. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just load events starting at block 0?

Comment: Do you have only address? if you have transaction hash, you can use function web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt

Comment: @smarx I though I could optimize event loading by getting the deployment block number

Comment: @kherwa Thanks, no I don't have txhash, otherwise it would be easy ;-)

Comment: Have you measured the performance difference? I would guess that an extra API call to figure out the deployment block takes way more time than whatever penalty there is for starting from block 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly looking for something more progamatic. A good starting point is the idea that each contract starts with a deployment transaction. It's always the first transaction in the contract history.

On Etherscan

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the `transactionHash` of the transaction which created your contract, you could just use the web3js function: `web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash [, callback])`

This will return you an object where you can access the block number you are looking for. Check [this](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=transactionhash#gettransaction) example code out!